# Dataproc can not auto-generate staging bucket

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-console

I am very new to gcloud and dataproc, and I use gcloud console.
Dataproc can not auto-generate staging buckets for my account, and every time I need to specify an existing bucket for every new cluster as 'staging bucket' when I configure cluster or it will show an error.

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Google Cloud Storage bucket does not exist 'dataproc-staging-<REDACTED>'.",
  "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

What should I do to it auto-generate staging bucket like it supposed to be? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you share your gcloud command used to create the cluster? You can get it from the "Equivalent REST or command line" below the Create button.

Comment: thank you for replying. the issue has been solved. it turns out that if you delete a staging bucket for a region before, then you will have such issue. I tried a new region (nv used before) and it is working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to reproduce this issue by deleting an existing staging bucket in the region and creating cluster in this region again, but during cluster creation Dataproc successfully recreated staging bucket - as expected.

Please, try to create a cluster in an original region to see if this issue is still reproducible for you.

Comment: Hi, I tried again by choosing a region I nv used before, and I successfully create the cluster; then I delete the cluster, as well as delete the staging bucket in storage;  then I tried to create another cluster in the region I just tested on, I can not create it anymore; it shows the same error above, saying missing bucket, i record the staging bucket name that I delete, which is the same as the name showing in the error...

Comment: This is weird, it works for me, what region did you try to use last time?